# How to create an "include all" file?

Tags: php, include

I would like to create "include all" file, and then from each "real" file instead of including bunch of files each time, include just created "include all" file.

Take a look at the example -- inc.php:

```
<?php
require_once('A/a.php');
require_once('A/B/b.php');
?>
```

A/a.php:

```
<?php
require_once('../inc.php'); 
?>
```

A/B/b.php:

```
<?php
require_once("../../inc.php");
?>
```

However it does not work -- if I execute "a.php" I got error that "inc.php" is not found included from "b.php", and when executing "b.php" per analogy from "a.php".

I don't see what is wrong with my code -- how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using OOP, definitely go for autoloading, as suggested by cjhill.

However if you are doing something less organized, and need to include files manually, I would suggest always using the `__DIR__` constant when specifying the include path. That way include paths will be relative to the file they are defined in, rather than the entry-point file.

```
include_once __DIR__ . "/../../includes.php".
```

You should think of "include" as a copy-paste, simply dropping the code from the included file into the position of the include call. As such, file paths within the included file will be relative to the originally requested file, unless you specify absolute paths, using something like `__DIR__`.

See [Magic Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) in the manual for details.

Comment: Thank you very much -- works as advertised :-) Opening slash is essential -- as I just learned it :-).

Answer (score 2):

You should look into autoloading in PHP to automatically include any class that hasn't already been included. It's very helpful: [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

[Also, here is a quick tutorial I wrote on the subject.](http://www.chrisjhill.co.uk/article/php-autoload-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly)

---

Alternatively, you could create a global PHP file (`global.php`) and just include that on every page. In the `global.php` it `include_once` all the files you need. But, like I said, method above is preferential.

Comment: Thank you. But this is completely other approach (I will read for sure, and thank you for that), and I would like to know what is wrong with this approach and how to fix it. As for that update -- it does not work as I showed.

Comment: What's wrong with your approach? It will get complicated quickly, and will run into errors like this. You want a centralised place for managing `include`'s. As for what is wrong with your code specifically, since it isn't the real code, it's hard to say - the logic seems OK.

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to use an absolute path like this :

Php < 5.3 :

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '../inc.php');
```

Php 5.3 :

```
require_once(__DIR__. '../inc.php');
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed, you have small error in your code, there should have been an opening slash after `__DIR__`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop. File A/a.pho is being included into file inc.php so why have an require at the top of file A/a.php for inc.pho?

The require function q the file in the parenthesis into the file the function is called from.

File A/a.php and A/B/B.php will inherit all scope data from inc.php upon their appendment into inc.php

Comment: All files are required, that is intended, otherwise you would have as many "all include" files as the actual files (each would have all except for the source of the inclusion). However there is no loop, because `require_once` instead of `require` -- PHP didn't crash with stack overflow after all.